# Integral of the $\delta$ function

Tags: integration

I want to calculate the integral defined as
$$
P(s)=\iint \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy\ \  \delta\left(\frac{(x+y)^2+4x^2y^2}{(x+y)^2+(x+y)^4}-s \right).
$$
The integration is taken within the rectangle $-a\le x,y\le a$. All I know is that $P(0)=0$. Is it possible to explicitly carry out this integral?

Comment: @SamHopkins. Maybe my question is somehow misleading. Actually, I want to compute the statistics of the function $f(x,y)$ mentioned in my question, and $x,y\in [-a,a]$ are uniformly distributed random numbers. If the integral in my question denotes indeed the statistics of $f(x,y)$ (please help me to check that), then it should not be zero for all $s$.

Comment: In principle, it's clear what to do - the $\delta $-distribution integrated over one of the variables, say $x$, will give contributions at all the zeros of the argument of the $\delta $-distribution as a function of $x$, and then the integral over $y$ is a standard integral yielding, in general, a finite result. The trouble is, the expressions for the aforementioned zeros are extremely ugly and I'm not going to attempt to write anything explicitly. Numerical evaluation seems more promising.

Comment: The function is linear (its derivative is constant) and vanishes for $s\leq 0$.

Comment: @terceira Sure, you have $P(s)=0$ for $s<0$.

Comment: Well  how many linear functions on the line do you know which vanish on the negative axis?

Comment: @terceira - Would I be able to apply your reasoning to the toy example I give in my answer just as well?

Comment: Maple's algcurves[genus]() says that for generic values of $s$, the argument of $\delta$ defines an algebraic curve of genus 1. This means that the curve can be parametrized by elliptic functions, or that the integral could be reduced to an elliptic integral (if the genus were 0, the parametrization could be done using rational or trigonometric functions, with corresponding simplifications for the integral, as in Michael Engelhardt's toy example). But I don't know if it will be worth it for you to go through that trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see how far we can get with the original problem. First, note that, since $x^2 y^2= \frac{1}{16} [(x+y)^4 + (x-y)^4 -2 (x+y)^2 (x-y)^2]$, the integrand is symmetric under reflections with respect to the $y=x$ axis and the $y=-x$ axis. Therefore, we can restrict the integration to the region $x+y \geq 0$, $x-y \leq 0$ (the remaining edge being the one at $y=a$), and just multiply the result by 4. Now, use the substitution suggested by @Guoqing,
$$
p=x+y\ , \hspace{2cm} q=\left( \frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{y} \right)^{-1}
$$
which inverts to
$$
x=\frac{p}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{p^2 }{4} -pq} \, \hspace{2cm}
y=\frac{p}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{p^2 }{4} -pq}
$$
(note our choice of integration region, $x\leq y$, makes the signs of the roots unique). Under this transformation, in the argument of the $\delta $-function,
$$
\frac{(x+y)^2 +4x^2 y^2 }{(x+y)^2+ (x+y)^4 } = \frac{1+4q^2 }{1+p^2 }
$$
and the Jacobian is
$$
\left| \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (p,q)} \right| = \frac{p}{2}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{p^2 }{4} -pq} }
$$
We elect to perform the integration over $q$ first. At any given, fixed $p=x+y$, the $q$-integration extends from the edge at $y=a$, from $x=p-a$, to the $x=y$ axis, at $x=y=\frac{p}{2} $. In terms of $q$, that is from $q=a-\frac{a^2 }{p} $ to $q=\frac{p}{4} $. The subsequent integration over $p$ extends from $p=0$ to $p=2a$.

The $\delta $-function yields contributions when
$$
\frac{1+4q^2 }{1+p^2 } = s \ \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ \ q=\pm \frac{1}{2}
\sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1}
$$
In particular, therefore, there are no contributions unless $s(1+p^2) \geq 1$.
Thus, the $\delta $-function can be expressed as
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta \left( \frac{1+4q^2 }{1+p^2 } -s \right) &=& \theta \left(s(1+p^2 ) -1\right) \ \frac{1+p^2}{8} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1} } \cdot \\
& & \left( \delta \left( q+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1} \right) +
\delta \left( q-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1} \right) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
Carrying out the integration over $q$, extending over $a-\frac{a^2 }{p} \leq q \leq \frac{p}{4} $, we thus obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
P(s) &=& 4\int_{0}^{2a} dp\ \ \theta \! \left(s(1+p^2 ) -1\right) \ 
\frac{(1+p^2)p}{8\sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1} } \cdot \\
& & \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4} + \frac{p}{2} \sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1} } }
\theta \left( -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1} -a +\frac{a^2 }{p} \right) \right. \\
& & \left. + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4} - \frac{p}{2} \sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1} } }
\theta \left( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1} -a +\frac{a^2 }{p} \right)
\theta \left( \frac{p}{4} -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{s(1+p^2 ) -1} \right)
\right]
\end{eqnarray}
A closed form for the $p$-integral does not seem immediately apparent, but a numerical integration offers itself.

Certainly, this result confirms the statement $P(0)=0$. In fact, $P(s)$ remains zero at least until $s=\frac{1}{1+4a^2 } $, when the upper limit of the $p$-integration comes within the range compatible with the condition $s(1+p^2 ) \geq 1$. The additional step functions in the final expression extend the range in which $P(s)$ remains zero even somewhat beyond the aforementioned bound.

Comment: Nice answer! Can I cite your answer in my paper?

Comment: @Guoqing - certainly, you can cite my answer. Or just put an acknowledgment. As you prefer. I'm happy that this was useful and would be interested in a pointer to your paper when it is finished.

Answer (score 8):

This is only the solution of a toy problem to illustrate how ugly this gets - much too long for a comment.

I'll consider
$$
\int_{-a}^{a} dy\int_{-a}^{a} dx\, \delta (x^2 +y^2 -s) 
$$
Focusing on the integration over $x$ first, we have
$$
\delta (x^2 +y^2 -s) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{s-y^2 } } \theta (s) \theta (s-y^2 ) \left(\delta \left(x-\sqrt{s-y^2 } \right) + \delta \left(x+\sqrt{s-y^2 } \right) \right)
$$
(where $\theta $ denotes the step function), and therefore
$$
\int_{-a}^{a} dx\, \delta (x^2 +y^2 -s) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{s-y^2 } } \theta (s) \theta (s-y^2 ) \left(\theta \left(a-\sqrt{s-y^2 } \right) +1 -\theta \left(\sqrt{s-y^2 } -a \right) \right)
$$
Note that this is manifestly even in $y$, so we can perform the subsequent $y$-integral as $\int_{-a}^{a} dy (\ldots ) = 2\int_{0}^{a} dy (\ldots )$.
Now, carefully distinguishing the different cases implied by the step functions, this results in
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-a}^{a} dy\, \int_{-a}^{a} dx\, \delta (x^2 +y^2 -s) &=&
2\theta (s) \theta (a^2-s) \int_{0}^{\sqrt{s} } dy\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{s-y^2 } } \\
& & + 2\theta (s-a^2) \theta (2a^2 -s) \int_{\sqrt{s-a^2 } }^{a} dy\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{s-y^2 } }
\end{eqnarray}
and therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-a}^{a} dy\, \int_{-a}^{a} dx\, \delta (x^2 +y^2 -s) &=&
\theta (s) \theta (a^2 -s) \pi \\
& & + 2\theta (s-a^2) \theta (2a^2 -s) \left[  \arcsin \frac{a}{\sqrt{s} } - \arcsin \frac{\sqrt{s-a^2 } }{\sqrt{s} } \right]
\end{eqnarray}
Now imagine having a quartic instead of a quadratic $\ldots $

Comment: Thanks for your enlightening answer. The only way I can get to deal with that quartic term is the changing variables as $x+y=p,1/x+1/y=1/q$ then you get a quadratic form within the delta function. But this will also introduce the complexity to the integral region :(

Comment: @Guoqing - ah, this transformation may nevertheless get you part of the way there: The $\delta $-function becomes fairly simple, the Jacobian can be evaluated, and the boundaries of the $q$-integral at given $p$ don't seem too complicated, whereupon that $q$-integral should be straightforward. Whether the $p$-integral is anywhere close to tractable is another matter, but it would surely be useful to have only one integral left ...